# VHDL : how to read / write data of 16 bits in RAM with 8 bits per address

Tags: vhdl

I have a VHDL code for reading and writing data of 8 bits to a RAM with 8 bits per address, but i need to make changes to the code in order to read/write data of 16 bits to the RAM with 8 bits per address.
What changes could be done?

The initial code i have is:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity RAM is
port(address: in std_logic_vector(0 to 15);
     datain: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
     dataout: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
     WE, CS, OE: in std_logic);
end entity RAM;

architecture behavior6 of RAM is
type RAM_type is array (0 to 2**16) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal RAM1: RAM_type;

begin
process (address, CS, WE, OE)
begin
dataout <= (others => 'Z'); --chip is not selected (this is the first row of the T.T)
if (CS = '0')
then

if WE= '0' then --we want to write
RAM1(to_integer(unsigned(address))) <= datain;
end if;

if WE= '1' and OE= '0'
then--we want to read
dataout <= RAM1(to_integer(unsigned(address)));
else
dataout <= (others => 'Z');
end if;
end if;
end process;
end behavior6;
```

Comment: Read/write data at two addresses. Or drop 2 of these entities into a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 library ieee;
 use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
 use ieee.numeric_std.all;
 entity RAM is
 port(address: in std_logic_vector(7 down to 0);
      datain: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
      dataout: out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
      WE, CS, OE: in std_logic);
 end entity RAM;
```

`architecture behavior6 of RAM is
     type RAM_type is array (255 down to 0) of std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
     signal RAM1:memory:=(others=>"0000000000000000");
     begin
     process (address, CS, WE, OE)
     variable a:integer range 0 to 255;
     begin
     a:=conv_integer(address);
     if (CS = '0')
     then
     if WE= '0' then
     RAM1(a)<=datain;
     end if;
     if WE= '1' and OE= '0' 
     then
     dataout<=RAM1(a);
     end if;
     end if;
     end process;
     end behavior6;`